# Finding src for WooCommerce downloadable product files to display in Audio Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, audio, woocommerce, shortcode

What I'm trying to do is add the default Wordpress audio shortcode to the content-single-product.php template from WooCommerce. I understand that the default shortcode is supposed to find any attached audio if there is none specified, but it's not behaving as such. I guess WooCommerce downloadable products handle file attachments differently?

This is the code I am using so far"

```html
$ca_audio = $product->get_id();
$attr = array(
 'src'      => $ca_audio,
 'loop'     => '',
 'autoplay' => '',
 'preload'  => 'none'
);
echo wp_audio_shortcode( $attr );
```

This is just displaying the product ID instead of a player. If i leave src blank it shows an empty player with no audio. If i put a direct link to the file it will play, but I need it to auto find the .mp3 file for each post automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to show audio file

```html
$ca_audio = $product->get_id();

$_product = wc_get_product( $ca_audio );
$downloads = $product->get_files();

foreach( $downloads as $key => $each_download ) {
   
 if ( strpos( $each_download["file"] , '.mp3') !== false) {
     $attr = array(
   'src'      => $each_download["file"],
   'loop'     => '',
   'autoplay' => '',
   'preload'  => 'none'
  );
  echo wp_audio_shortcode( $attr );
  break;
 }
}
```

The audio file is correctly embedded but it is not playing. When I open the file directly, it gives 401 Forbidden error. It is a woocommerce downloadable product access security feature. Maybe you need to manually embed audio files in each product.

Comment: Hi Manik. There is a plugin "Music Player for WooCommerce" that seems to automatically pull the files in the manner I am trying to acheive, but I can't add it to just my product page, so it pulls the audio for every product location on the site (i.e. the home page newest products section, related products) and bogs down the site.

I wonder how he is able to get around the WooCommerce product access security?

Comment: The author of the plugin I was mentioning said he is able to do it by "using a PHP Script as proxy." I am not familiar with this at all, is it something I can achieve with minimal code?

Comment: You can enable the music player plugin only for product pages using this plugin.
Plugin organizer [link]https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/
If audio files also loads on related product - then you can hide them using css